# Can a mobile broadband box (example link inside) be used as a network extender or a router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

For example, ones like these: https://shop.ee.co.uk/dongles/pay-monthly-mobile-broadband/gallery#

Specifically, I want to the mobile broadband box to connect to a Public Wi-Fi and then create a private network out of it so I can connect all my Wi-Fi enabled devices in the house and link them, e.g Chromecast or Sonus speakers. This does obviously have a network login page so I don't know how much harder that would make it. I do know actual router's are cheap but if I avoid spending money (even small amounts) then why not. Also I have no spare device that I can just leave a hotspot on and I don't want to make a hotspot of my laptop or phone because they are constantly leaving and returning to the home.

I'm guessing no because I'm assuming they are designed in such a way - *what ever I mean by that* - however I could not find anything online about it so I thought I would I just ask here for conformation, thanks.